ArrayFormula which shows Rows that match multiple columns conditions
I got a Sales Promotions spreadsheet where I must have a Column which shows the Rows of conflicts of same product being promoted in same dates and different sales representatives.
Columns:
E: Retail Name
F: Sales Representative
L: Product SKU Code
I: Start Date of Promotion
J: End Date of Promotion
M: Sales Chanel (On, Off, On+Off)
=array_constrain((IF(and($E$4:$E<>"";$L$4:$L<>"";$I$4:$I<>"";$J$4:$J<>"";$M$4:$M<>"";$F$4:$F<>"");arrayformula(TEXTJOIN(", ";TRUE;IF(($F1102<>$F$4:$F)($I1102<=$J$4:$J)($J1102>=$I$4:$I)*($L1102=$L$4:$L);IF(ROW($I$4:$I)=ROW();"";"Row"&ROW($I$4:$I));"")));""));COUNTA($E$4:$E);1)

Questions:

This formula shows a error "Did Not Find valeu 'a' in VLOOKUP evaluation", which I do not get, once I don't have VLOOKUP inside the formula. Once I cut of the "($F1102<>$F$4:$F)", it works just fine.

Also the array_constrain is not autofilling the column to the line of last value in Column E.



Post few of a sample data and then show your desired output. You may also share a sample google-sheet.

Concatenate multiple values to use as a search key
Based on my research it would be difficult to use an ARRAYFORMULA for your issue. This is because, the main reason you can't use ARRAYFORMULA with your original formula is that ARRAYFORMULA does not handle concatenation functions like JOIN directly due to how these functions aggregate data. Breaking down the problem into helper columns and then combining results is a common approach to work around these limitations.
If I were planning to resolve this issue, I would start with this formula.
NOTE: These formulas might not perfectly fit 100% on your use case but you can use this as a reference to get an answer to your question.
={SEQUENCE(ROWS(F2:F20)), F2:F20, BYROW(G2:I20, LAMBDA(row, CONCATENATE(row)))}

I used this formula to create a list of numbers which we can use to identify which rows are conflicting and to concatenate values in each row, so, it would be easier for me to identify the similarities of each row, and then merge these results with the original range.
Then I would use this second formula on a nearby cell.
=IF(
    REGEXMATCH(JOIN(",", FILTER($K$2:$K$20, $M$2:$M$20 = M2)), ","),
    "Conflicting rows: " & JOIN(",", FILTER($K$2:$K$20, $M$2:$M$20 = M2)),
    "")

I used FILTER to detect conflicts where multiple promotions might overlap or have issues and JOIN to aggregate all these entries into a single comma-separated string. I also use the REGEXMATCH to  validate whether the concatenated string contains multiple entries.
This is the sample dataset that I have created based on your column requirements, as well as the first formula on K2 and the second formula on N2:

References:

Arrayformula
Sequence
Byrow
Lambda
Concatenate
IF
Regexmatch
Join
Filter

